# Is there a way to get playlist metadata with ffmpeg without reading segments?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, streaming, video-streaming

I'm using a command `ffmpeg -i file.m3u8` to parse `.m3u8` file and get it's metadata

Everything's good if at least one of the segment listed presents, but is there any way to get meta info without parsing segments? I mean, some minimal details, like duration, bandwidth, or resolution?

Comment: If the playlist contains that data, just download the playlist and parse it. If not, ffmpeg has to probe the segments.